# using wsock32 to send email with gmail and startTLS

Tags: c++, email

Hello and good evening to you,

This topic has been sort of a trouble to me and to many, suppose i want to send EMail in a C++ program to use smtp and StartTLS , what do i do, i culled a simple source code from google and i saw this code from here

http://www.drdobbs.com/sending-e-mail-using-smtp-and-winsock/184416591

now i want to use google mail and it uses authentication for smtp and also startTLS how do i do this

the sourcecode i saw looks like this

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include "MailMessage.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MailMessage mail("A Sender",
    "someone@someplace.com",
    "mail.someplace.com");
  mail.To("A Recipient",
    "you@yourplace.com");
  mail.Subject("Sample message");

  mail.Body("Plain text body",
    "<HTML><BODY>\r\n"
    " <H2>HTML Body</H2>\r\n"
    "</BODY></HTML>""\r\n");

  mail.Attach("C:\\Attach.txt");

  const char *result =
    mail.Send().data();

  if (result[0] == '\0')
    result = "Success";

  MessageBox(NULL, result, "Result",
    MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: My question is how can i send email using gmail with gmail smtp and enable TLS ? It should connect to gmail server (smtp.gmail.com) on port 587 with username and password and send email

Comment: You can achieve this by following `STARTTLS` spec and implementing TLS channel with encryption and decryption of the data. You send the same SMTP commands, same syntax, just over secured channel.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to the server and issuing a `EHLO` (not `HELO`) command, if the server's reply includes the `STARTTLS` capability then you can issue a `STARTTLS` command at any time to create a secure session with the server.  Upon receiving a successful `STARTTLS` reply, you need to send and complete an SSL/TLS handshake.  Once the session has been created, you can continue sending your SMTP commands and receiving SMTP replies, starting with a new `EHLO` command (as the server's capabilities can change after the connection is secured).  You have to encrypt your commands and decrypt the replies as you go.  The communication would look like this (this example assumes an Application-Specific password has been configured in GMail if two-step verification is enabled):

```
S:    220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP dg12sm55710335pac.47 - gsmtp
C:    EHLO <hostname>
S:    250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [<ip address>]
S:    250-SIZE 35882577
S:    250-8BITMIME
S:    250-STARTTLS
S:    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S:    250-PIPELINING
S:    250-CHUNKING
S:    250 SMTPUTF8
C:    STARTTLS
S:    220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C/S:  (Exchange SSL/TLS handshake)
C/S:  (Everything from here on is now encrypted)
C:    EHLO <hostname>
S:    250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [<ip address>]
S:    250-SIZE 35882577
S:    250-8BITMIME
S:    250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
S:    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S:    250-PIPELINING
S:    250-CHUNKING
S:    250 SMTPUTF8
C:    AUTH LOGIN
S:    334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C:    (Send base64 encoded username)
S:    334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C:    (Send base64 encoded password)
S:    235 2.7.0 Accepted
C:    (Send email as needed)
C:    QUIT
S:    221 2.0.0 closing connection m1sm91929700pfi.27 - gsmtp
```

Now, how you actually handle the encryption is up to you.  You can use a library like OpenSSL, or you can use Microsoft's Crypto/SChannel API.  There are plenty of online tutorials and books on how to use them with sockets.